# DataTables and jQuery Validation plugin

Tags: jquery, datatables, jeditable

I am very new to DataTables and jQuery Validation Plugin.
Is there a *standard* way to add client-side validation to a DataTable ?
(note that user is allowed to removed/add rows)
Please, do not ask me "what have you tried yet, does it fail to work ?", I have tried searching but nothing interesting comes out, so the only alternative atm looks like writing specific code, which sounds sub-optimal to me considering that seems like a *very common and generic* problem.

My project is bundled with the following dependencies (some are old, which is why finding examples and advice is harder):

> - jQuery Validation Plugin 1.11.1 (this: https://github.com/jquery-validation/jquery-validation/releases/tag/1.11.1)
> - DataTables 1.9.4
> - jQuery 1.3.2, jQuery 2.0.3
> - "jQuery UI" (no idea what this is) 1.7.2
> - Jeditable (this: https://appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/) 1.7.1
> - jquery.inputmask.bundle.js (?)

Comment: https://editor.datatables.net/examples/api/clientValidation.html check this link

Comment: Thanks for the link, however please note I'm working with an old version of DataTables (which has changed after 1.9). What is left of the legacy documentation is there http://legacy.datatables.net/ref

Comment: Besides, I'm not using the Editor plugin (which is a paid product).